# md5sums are wrong on 2 downloads downloading a 3rd now

Tags: lts, md5sum

md5sums have been wrong on 2 of my downloads of ubuntu Desktop, checked all sums on the page with software link ubuntu provided, what's up?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like bad downloads. Maybe your web browser or downloading program (or something mysterious) is doing something wrong. And checking against the right [Ubuntu md5 hashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)?

Try using the **torrent** download (under [Alternative downloads and torrents](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)) to get the file, it's uber-good at handling interrupted downloads and it does it's own error-checking too.